# How to convert a class declaration to a string using macros?

Tags: c++, serialization, reflection, macros

I need to convert my class declaration into a string and I also need the class defined. in the code below i have given an example which results in `Identifier Person is undefined` or `Incomplete type not allowed`. but if this is possible with custom macros, some code would be much appreciated.

```
struct Person;
std::string Person::meta = STRINGIFY(
    struct Person{
        static std::string meta;
        std::string name = "Test";
        int age = 5;
        std::string address = "No:35179 Address";
    };
);
Person person;
```

Comment: Please do not add language tags for unrelated languages. That is clearly no C code.

Comment: What is `STRINGIFY()`? Where do you get that macro from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that; you can't initialize `Person::meta` before the type is defined, and you can't define the type as part of the initializing expression.

However, you can move the initialization into the macro:

```
#define WITH_META(cls, body) struct cls body; std::string cls::meta = "struct " #cls #body;

WITH_META(Person, {
        static std::string meta;
        std::string name = "Test";
        int age = 5;
        std::string address = "No:35179 Address";
    });

int main()
{
    std::cout << Person::meta << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
struct Person{static std::string meta; std::string name = "Test"; int age = 5; std::string address = "No:35179 Address";}
```